# Pandas Dataframe - (Column re structure)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, gspread

I have a dataframe that has n number of columns. These contain letters, the amount of letters a column contains varies and a letter can appear in various amounts of columns. I need the code for a pandas dataframe to convert the sheet to columns starting with the letters, the rows should contain the numbers of the columns that that letter was in.

[Link to example problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ph15h.png)

[image]

1234. ```
        ABCDEF
      ```

ABDE.      11     1
BBCC ->    2        2
EFB.           3 3
4  4

The image describes my problem better. Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Can you convert that image to actual text data and share please?

Comment: I attempted to convert it to text data. I can do the question in a text file if that would help also?

Comment: I attempted to convert it to text data. I can do the question in a text file if that would help also?

Comment: you have the answer from Jezrael. It should help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for reshape, then [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and aggregate `list`s, last create `DataFrame` by constructor with transpose:

```
s=df.stack().reset_index(name='a').sort_values('level_1').groupby('a')['level_1'].agg(list)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(s.tolist(), index=s.index).T
print (df1)
a     a  b     c     d     e     f
0     1  1     1     1     3     2
1     3  3     2     4     4  None
2  None  4  None  None  None  None
```

Or use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter and reshape by [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df2 = df.stack().reset_index(name='a').sort_values('level_1')

df2['g'] = df2.groupby('a').cumcount()

df2 = df2.pivot('g','a','level_1')
print (df2)
a    a  b    c    d    e    f
g                            
0    1  1    1    1    3    2
1    3  3    2    4    4  NaN
2  NaN  4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Last if necessary remove index and columns names:

```
df1 = df1.rename_axis(index=None)
df2 = df2.rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
```